# Amended As Published

Tags: phrase-meaning, legalese, ellipsis, as

I am a little bit confused reading [this](http://www.grassicpas.com/healthcare/compliance-with-the-hipaa-omnibus-rule-deadline-is-92313-are-you-ready/):

> Under the new HIPAA Mega rule published in January 2013, portions of the HIPAA Privacy Rule and portions of the HIPAA Security Rule were dramatically ***amended as published*** by the Department of Health and Human Services (DHHS).

What does "*amended as published*" mean?

Answer (score 1):

*Amended as published* means that the document has been republished in a different form.
This often occurs when a document from some official body is republished by a higher body.

In your example, the document was originally published by HIPAA. 
A revised version was published by DHHS.

The revised version was altered, so the republished version had amendments.
The document is amended *as published by DHSS*.

Comment: HIPAA is not an entity, but a law. Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act

Comment: @TimRomano It does seem to have taken on a life of its own, though. :P

Answer (score 1):

Absence of punctuation and an ellipsis are the cause of your confusion.  It should be punctuated "amended, as published by ..."

"amended, as published by" = "amended, as set forth in the current version put out by..."